# kubernetes - trouble adding node to cluster

Tags: kubernetes

by following the information in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o6bxo0Oeg6o&t=1s),
I was able to get a control plane running on my kmaster vm.

```
jason@kmaster:~$ kubectl get pods -A
NAMESPACE     NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-59697b644f-tpxnn   1/1     Running   0          18h
kube-system   calico-node-88l8f                          1/1     Running   0          18h
kube-system   coredns-565d847f94-vpzwg                   1/1     Running   0          18h
kube-system   coredns-565d847f94-wkv4p                   1/1     Running   0          18h
kube-system   etcd-kmaster                               1/1     Running   0          18h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-kmaster                     1/1     Running   0          18h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-kmaster            1/1     Running   0          18h
kube-system   kube-proxy-wd2gh                           1/1     Running   0          18h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-kmaster                     1/1     Running   0          18h
```

Here are my network interfaces:

```
jason@kmaster:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens18: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e6:ec:4b:b8:37:7a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s18
    inet 10.0.10.118/24 brd 10.0.10.255 scope global ens18
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2600:8802:5700:46d::164d/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute
       valid_lft 4863sec preferred_lft 2163sec
    inet6 2600:8802:5700:46d:e4ec:4bff:feb8:377a/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 86385sec preferred_lft 14385sec
    inet6 fe80::e4ec:4bff:feb8:377a/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:bb:62:1c:c5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: calida7207728a2@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet6 fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: cali919c5dc3a63@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet6 fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: cali0657a847784@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 2
    inet6 fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: tunl0@NONE: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1480 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ipip 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
    inet 192.168.189.0/32 scope global tunl0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I am now trying to add a node to the cluster by using the following command:

```
sudo kubeadm join 10.0.10.118:6443 --token <token>         --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:<hash>
Found multiple CRI endpoints on the host. Please define which one do you wish to use by setting the 'criSocket' field in the kubeadm configuration file: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock, unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock
To see the stack trace of this error execute with --v=5 or higher
```

As you can see it says 'please define which one you wish to use by setting the 'criSocket' field in the kubeadm configuration file. However when I try to edit /var/run/cri-dockerd.sock file, it says it's not a normal file:

```
cri-dockerd.sock is not a regular file (use -f to see it)
```

Here is my kubeadm config print:

```
jason@kmaster:~$ kubectl get pods -A --watch
NAMESPACE     NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS        AGE
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-59697b644f-tpxnn   1/1     Running   2 (6m56s ago)   16d
kube-system   calico-node-88l8f                          1/1     Running   2 (6m56s ago)   16d
kube-system   coredns-565d847f94-vpzwg                   1/1     Running   2 (6m51s ago)   16d
kube-system   coredns-565d847f94-wkv4p                   1/1     Running   2 (6m51s ago)   16d
kube-system   etcd-kmaster                               1/1     Running   2 (6m56s ago)   16d
kube-system   kube-apiserver-kmaster                     1/1     Running   2 (6m55s ago)   16d
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-kmaster            1/1     Running   2 (6m56s ago)   16d
kube-system   kube-proxy-wd2gh                           1/1     Running   2 (6m56s ago)   16d
kube-system   kube-scheduler-kmaster                     1/1     Running   2 (6m56s ago)   16d
^Cjason@kmaster:~kubeadm config print init-defaults
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3
bootstrapTokens:
- groups:
  - system:bootstrappers:kubeadm:default-node-token
  token: abcdef.0123456789abcdef
  ttl: 24h0m0s
  usages:
  - signing
  - authentication
kind: InitConfiguration
localAPIEndpoint:
  advertiseAddress: 1.2.3.4
  bindPort: 6443
nodeRegistration:
  criSocket: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  name: node
  taints: null
---
apiServer:
  timeoutForControlPlane: 4m0s
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta3
certificatesDir: /etc/kubernetes/pki
clusterName: kubernetes
controllerManager: {}
dns: {}
etcd:
  local:
    dataDir: /var/lib/etcd
imageRepository: registry.k8s.io
kind: ClusterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: 1.25.0
networking:
  dnsDomain: cluster.local
  serviceSubnet: 10.96.0.0/12
scheduler: {}
```

Under nodeRegistration it says:
nodeRegistration:
criSocket: unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock

In /var/run/
I see cri-dockerd.sock

```
jason@kmaster:/var/run$ ls -la
total 28
srw-rw----  1 root docker    0 Nov 15 00:25 cri-dockerd.sock
```

How can I add my node to the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

You can choose which CRI you would like to use directly from the join command by adding this flag: (see `kubeadm join --help` for details)

```
--cri-socket string
```

here, string will be one of the two available sockets displayed in the error:

1. `unix:///var/run/containerd/containerd.sock`
2. `unix:///var/run/cri-dockerd.sock`

Or you can also add it to you kubeadm config as stated
see doc here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/config-api/kubeadm-config.v1beta3/#kubeadm-k8s-io-v1beta3-NodeRegistrationOptions

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by starting over, installing ubuntu 20.04 and then creating cluster again. But it believe maxxvw is correct.